# Bin-packing Algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Let's say I have $n$ bins of different sizes $A$ and I have $m$ pieces of also different sizes $B$ which I want to pack inside of the bins.

The size of $A$ and $B$ are equal hence $|A| = |B|$ and $m>=n$. What would be the best algorithm to ensure that no space is wasted with unnecessary additional bins?

Comment: Perhaps this would be a better question for computer science overflow

Comment: I think the answer involves Dynamic Programming

Comment: I've experienced that people with a math background usually have better ideas and knowledge when it comes to algorithmic tasks. That's why I wanted to try it here.